# Store data in NSArray in custom class and use in other class/controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am really stuck at a small point while making my first app, have tried various posts on SOF and many variations but not able to do what I want to do.
I have a UITableViewController that needs some data, the data it needs I am populating in a NSArray in a custom data class I made to manage all the data my project needs.
I have a instance variable/property in my data class and it gets the data needed from a function. The data is showing well and good in the function but I cant access it in my main TableView function, I tried making data class object and access it but shows null.

Here is some sample code.

dataClass.h

```
@interface GDAPIhandler : NSObject {  
        NSMutableArray *relImageUrl;  
    }  
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *timeLine;  
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *relImageUrl;
```

dataClass.m

```
self.relImageUrl = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.relImageUrl addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:thumb]];
```

tableViewController.h

```
#import "dataClass.h"
```

tableViewControll.m

```
dataClass *test = [dataClass alloc] init; 
test.relImageUrl      //this is nil
```

I have init and called functions and classes properly in my code, above is for example of what I am doing but that is the situation I am in.
Any help would be appreciated

---- Real InCode After Trying what I understood reading comments -----
the data source class

[image: the data source class]

The Table View Class

[image: The Table view class where I want to use the array in, I have already included the datasource class]

Comment: in which method are the two lines from `dataClass.m`
 ?

Comment: you are allocating but you are not assign the value of funcWithData. Then without assign the value what you can expect rather than nil

Comment: @KIDdAe as per my example that would be funcWithData method, actually that method has a async dispatch which stores the data (BG fetching)

Comment: @TapasPal my bad, I have edited the question, the method actually has a dispatch BG process which fetches images from a API and has to store them in the array (in BG run so app doesnt have to wait for it), the function itself doesnt returns anything

Comment: Did you override dataClass `init` method ? If yes, could you please share it ?
If no, `relImageUrl` is nil because `funWithData` has not been called

Comment: @KIDdAe tbh I started obj C 2 days ago so not sure what you mean by override init, I have uploaded a screen of my code of function where and how I am storing my data, have a look - [http://i.imgur.com/ThYVqlC.png](http://i.imgur.com/ThYVqlC.png)

Comment: This is a duplicate of several hundred prior "access data in class x from class y" questions, but I'm too lazy to look up a reference.

Comment: (And please don't include images of code -- copy/paste the code directly.)  (At least in this case the images are semi-legible -- usually they're not.)

Comment: @HotLicks I have checked like 19 threads till now, none were able to help me, mostly I think my problem is either blocks or that dispatch_async and I uploaded imgs as felt it will be more readable than plain text code

Answer (score 0):

Please check the project in link https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/Tableview. I did a mock up of what you needed. I have the data source populated in a external object which is used to populate the tableview.

I think the problem is your haven't initialised your NSMutable array and allocated it in the object you are creating. You need to have the NSMutableArray init and alloc somewhere after your object is created before accessing it. You can init and alloc array in your data class init method or else write a custom method and call that custom method once data object is created.

method 1:
SourceData.m

```
@implementation SourceData

-(id) init
{
  self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
       relImageURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       [relImageURL addObject:@"FirstRow"];
    }

    return self;

}
```

In tableviewcontroller

```
SourceData *sourceData = [[SourceData alloc]init];
tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceData relImageURL]];
// tabledata is a private variable
```

Method 2:(Custom init method for Array)

```
@implementation SourceData

-(void) initTableSource
{
     relImageURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       [relImageURL addObject:@"FirstRow"];
}
```

In tableviewcontroller

```
SourceData *sourceData = [[SourceData alloc]init];
[sourceData initTableSource];
NSLog(@"%@",[sourceData relImageURL])
```

Comment: I am checking your source project atm, but here is the screen of my code in the class I am storing the data [http://i.imgur.com/ThYVqlC.png](http://i.imgur.com/ThYVqlC.png)

Comment: Looking at user2897064's screenshot, he's trying to assign to/create the array inside a block without the __block storage modifier.  Without it, you can't mutate an object inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

First off, unless you are doing something special with your instance variable (relImageUrl) get rid of it as it isn't needed.  If you keep it, make sure you synthesize it properly -- and current convention is to prefix it with an underscore (as in _relImageUrl).  But again, you probably don't need it at all.

You haven't shown anything of the getter/setter for relImageUrl so assuming you aren't doing anything special there.

You also show your private class interface as GDAPIhandler but you refer to it as dataClass.h -- this makes no sense.

How do you set the item count for table view if you don't actually add any elements until you request it as above?

Ideally, you'd have an NSArray property in your custom class and methods that operate on it by exposing:

1. a method to get the count of items
2. a method to pull out an item an a given index
3. possibly methods to add/remove items
4. methods to instantiate/populate the array -- but please don't do it as you request cells as you seem to be doing.....that approach will not end well

All this assumes you are trying to use your custom class to 'hide' access to the underlying array.  Suggest you refactor along some of these lines to make things easier for yourself going forward.

UPDATE

I just saw your screen shot for the last response.  Not sure how you expect folks to help when you don't share all the relevant info.

If you want to assign to relImageUrl inside a block, you need to prefix it with the __block storage modifier.  Further, don't refer to self inside the block as it could lead to retain cycles.

So, you could try something like (inside your function but before you enter any blocks).

```
__weak CustomClass* weakSelf = self;  // don't capture self in block 
__block NSMutableArray* weakImageUrl = weakSelf.relImageUrl;
```

..try something along those lines.  Two main points again:

1. don't refer to self inside the block
2. use __block storage modifier for any objects you need to mutate inside the block

...good luck...

Comment: removed ivar as yeah wasnt making any special use of it but added by reading some posts trying to make work what I needed, GDApiHandler and dataClass are same, GDApi one is real name, dataClass is a dummy name I used for example

Comment: can you tell me the example you gave referring to my own code as per my screen ? is weak prefix just for convinience or it plays any part like _ ? And can _relImageUrl be used without adding synthesize or should I add it ?

Comment: You can refer to _relImageUrl in your implementation without creating the backing variable. It will be created for you by virtue of the @property definition by default -- unless you override the setter/getter then you WILL need to explicitly synthesize it.

Comment: My code example was merely a suggestion based on the screen shot you submitted above -- I suspect your real problem is when you set the array inside your block -- that it isn't retained because you don't have the correct storage modifier to tell XCode to retain it -- hence __block is needed somewhere.  I just gave one example of how to do it inside your function BEFORE you enter the block.  Somewhere at the top of runQue

Comment: not using any such get and set, I have replaced code in implementation with `[_relImageUrl addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:thumb]];` and in tableview class where I want it, I created a object of my API class, and using object.relImageUrl but its still nil  
Also, basically what I am doing and why I am not or dont know how to use a return function to get this data is, I am using async dispatch to fetch all image data during app launch (in BG) so when user sees table view, all needed image data is in a array

Comment: Suggest you update your question to show everything -- too hard to try and piece together the above plus your screenshot.  If your array, _relImageUrl is nil, you are never going to be able to add an object to it.  So that needs to be sorted first.  For example, you say your are creating your API class and adding to it in your tableview class. Are you subclassing tableview, using a tableviewcontroller or creating a direct tableview?  Where are you doing this in the taleview?  cellForRowIndexPath?  Show that code.  Make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I have updated the main post with new screenshots trying what I understood after reading your replies, also I am unable to use _block as I tried using it before that dummy array I made but Xcode shows its a undefined identifier or such

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNotificationCenter for posting data to another class

Comment: I am not at all sure how to use NSNotif in my case, also am not sure how it will be viable in what I am trying to do

Comment: Its very simple just you have to add the obeserver in your reciever class and post the notification in sender class means when you post the notification you have to pass the object which is your array. Syntax you will get in the google. If you are not able to send let me know

Comment: I changed my approach already, the problem was due to using dispatch_async, also I am thinking to use notification center but do it has any demerits like for some large data or such

Comment: There is no any demerits you can send large data as well but merits of notification is that you can broadcast your messages for muliple reciever.